# Phoenix Live View live navigation with `patch` issue in liveview 0.20.0

Tags: phoenix-framework, phoenix-live-view

Out of curiosity, I updated my live_view from 0.19.5 to the current 0.20.0 and quickly realized that my patch on my <.link> is not re-rendering/updating my live view.

```
<.link
    patch={
      ~p"/budgets?#{%{@options | sort_by: @sort_by, sort_order: next_sort_order(@options.sort_order)}}"
    }
>
  <%= render_slot(@inner_block) %>
  <%= sort_indicator(@sort_by, @options) %>
</.link>
```

I quickly checked with IO.inspect inside my handle_params to see if my options (and my budgets) were changing, and they were.

here’s my handle_params

```
def handle_params(params, _uri, socket) do
    current_user = socket.assigns.current_user
    sort_by = valid_sort_by(params)
    sort_order = valid_sort_order(params)
    page = param_to_integer(params["page"], 1)
    per_page = param_to_integer(params["per_page"], 36)
    date = Date.utc_today()
    year = param_to_integer(params["year"], date.year)
    month = param_to_integer(params["month"], date.month)

    options = %{
      sort_by: sort_by,
      sort_order: sort_order,
      page: page,
      per_page: per_page,
      year: year,
      month: month
    }

    budgets = Keihi.list_budgets(current_user, options)

   # both options and budgets change per click of my <.link> tag
   # IO.inspect(options, label: "options")
   # IO.inspect(budgets, label: "budgets")

    socket =
      socket
      |> stream(:budgets, budgets)
      |> assign(:selected_budget, select_budget(budgets, param_to_integer(params["id"], 0)))
      |> assign(:options, options)
  
    {:noreply, socket}
end
```

I also tried to set the stream to reset likeso:

```
|> stream(:budgets, budgets, reset: true)
```

with no changes.

Any clues? Of course I don't have to update the versions, but I’m wondering if I’m doing something wrong here.